# Url error when js file is on public

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I make a .js file in public folder on Laravel, /assets/js/cms.js

I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    listProject();
    $("#buttoncreate").click(function(e){
        $("#buttoncreate").remove();
        e.preventDefault();
        listUploadProject();
    });
});

var listProject = function()
{
    $.ajax({
        type:'get',
        url:"{{ url('admin/project/listall') }}",
        success: function(data){
            $('#ajaxwindow').empty().html(data);
        }
    });
}

var listUploadProject = function()
{
     $.ajax({
         type:'get',
         url:"{{ url('admin/project/create') }}",
         success: function(data){
           $('#ajaxwindow').empty().html(data);
         }
     });
}
```

And when the view is loaded, call to this url:

> http://web.loc/admin/%7B%7B%20url('admin/project/listall')%20%7D%7D

And don't load the listall and give me an url error.

How to fix it?

If need more info, say it please. It will be appreciated any help.

**SOLVED**
The problem was i copy the code from the blade to a .js script, so i can't put {{}} on url.
Now looks like this:

```
//Javascript view /projects/menu.blade.php
$(document).ready(function(){
      listProject();
      $("#buttoncreate").click(function(e){
        $("#buttoncreate").remove();
        e.preventDefault();
        listUploadProject();
      });
    });

      var listProject = function()
      {
        $.ajax({
          type:'get',
          url:"/admin/project/listall",
          success: function(data){
            $('#ajaxwindow').empty().html(data);
          }
        });
      }
      var listUploadProject = function()
     {
       $.ajax({
         type:'get',
         url:"/admin/project/create",
         success: function(data){
           $('#ajaxwindow').empty().html(data);
         }
       });
     }
```

Comment: why do you load the url like that? It seems you need to include some form of framework to build a URL from that expression

Comment: Are you using Angular ??

Comment: @Maraboc fixed mate!

Comment: @LucaKiebel just cause before i have the code in the blade, now it's fixed. without {{}} works!. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Blade does not work inside the double quotes. Try doing it this way: `{!! json_encode(url('admin/project/listall')) !!}`

Comment: My fault, i just upload the question and fixed it;) Thanks anyway!

Comment: Yes, but you've hard-coded the routes in the end. If you now move those to a section/group - your code will fail :(

Comment: In routes i have views like this:     Route::get('project/create', ['uses' => 'AdminController@createProject', 'as' => 'admin.projects.formupload']);
always with a 'as' i think, i call it with this, true?